# How to install mongo legacy shell in MongoDB 6.0

Tags: mongodb, debian, mongo-shell

The legacy `mongo` shell has been removed in MongoDB 6.0. Following the [official Debian installation procedure for 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/), it is not intalled (in favour of the new `mongosh` shell).

However, due to some legacy reasons, I need also the old shell. Is there any documented way of installing the legacy `mongo` in Debian in that case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to install/download an old version of MongoDB. Then you can copy the `mongo` binary to your machine.